# jquery checkbox check using arrays

Tags: jquery

I was trying to check check-boxes using array in jquery using multiple select options
If, lets say Option 1 and Option 3 is clicked, checkboxes which id is set in array will become checked and if removed unchecked.

```html
<select id="lab_abbr" multiple >
  <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

and checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[one]" id="lab_one" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[two]" id="lab_two" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[three]" id="lab_three" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[four]" id="lab_four" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[five]" id="lab_five" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[six]" id="lab_six" />
```

and last jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lab_abbr").live("change", function(e)  {
        var o1 = ['lab_one', 'lab_three'];
        var o2 = ['lab_two', 'lab_six'];
        var o3 = ['lab_four, 'lab_five'];


    });
});
```

Regards,
Besmir

Comment: You're saying, if somebody selects "Option 1" in the select, you want to check "lab_three" in the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes if someone select Option 1, I want to check "lab_three" and "lab_one" and if Option 1 is deselected "lab_three" and "lab_one" to become unchecked

Comment: I have worked up a very short solution below. I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Give a man fish...

```
var mapping = { 'o1' : ['lab_one', 'lab_three'], 'o2' : ['lab_two', 'lab_six'], 
                'o3' : ['lab_four', 'lab_five'] };

$("#lab_abbr").on("change", function () {
  $.each( this.options, function () {
    $( "#" + mapping[ this.value ].join(", #") ).prop("checked", this.selected); 
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/onapem/edit#javascript,html

#### Teach a man to fish...

Let's break it down now and see what each part does.

We start off by creating an object which will serve as a sort of associative array. Essentially, we get to associate one value to another. In this case, we want to associate the value of the selected option (be it "o1" or "o2"), to a series of checkboxes:

```
var mapping = { 'o1' : ['lab_one', 'lab_three'] };
```

Next we bind our logic to the `change` event of our `select` menu using the `$.on` method:

```
$("#lab_abbr").on("change", function(){
  /* React to the change */
});
```

Anytime this menu undergoes a change, we want to cycle over its options. We're not yet worried about whether or not the options are selected - we just want to access every one of them. We do so by using the `$.each` iterator method:

```
$.each( this.options, function(){
  /* Do something with each individual <option /> */
});
```

Within this block, we want to gather up those checkbox id's that are associated with this option value. For instance, if we wanted all values associated with "o1" (which would represent the first option through our `$.each`, we could do this:

```
alert( mapping['o1'] ); // ['lab_one', 'lab_three']
```

We're going t do this dynamically though. Within our `$.each`, the keyword `this` always refers to the current `<option />` being handled. We can use its value to look up any fields associated with it:

```
mapping[ this.value ]; // returns an array
```

We would like to convert this into a CSS selector to pass jQuery, so we use the `.join()` method on the returned array to create a string:

```
mapping[ this.value ].join(", #");
```

The `.join()` method accepts a string to add between each value. In the case above, our first iteration through will return in the following string:

```
"lab_one, #lab_three"
```

Note the `, #` seperating the two values from the array. We need another `#` in the front of this string so that `#lab_one` will also be selected. This was solved by concatenating the character onto the resulting string:

```
$( "#" + mapping[ this.value ].join(", #") )
```

Lastly, we call the `$.prop()` method which allows us to set a property value on the element. We're going to set the `checked` property.

With the `$.prop()` method, you pass in the property you would like to set, and the value you would like to set it to.

```
$( /*...*/ ).prop("checked", this.selected );
```

Remember, `this` represents whichever `<option />` we're currently accessing in this iteration of `$.each()`. The `<option />` has a native property called `selected` which returns either `true` or `false` - indicating if it's selected or not. We use this to tell jQuery what the value of `"checked"` should be.

So if the option being handled is `selected`, so will each one of the checkboxes it is associated with. And likewise, if the option being handled is not selected, neither will the checkboxes it is associated with.

#### Want a smaller fish?

If you wanted to shorten this all a bit more, you could store the jQuery selector directly in the object:

```
var mapping = { 'o1' : '#lab_one, #lab_three', 'o2' : '#lab_two, #lab_six',
                'o3' : '#lab_four, #lab_five' };

$("#lab_abbr").on("change", function () {
  $.each( this.options, function () {
    $( mapping[ this.value ] ).prop( "checked", this.selected ); 
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/onapem/2/edit

Comment: mapping var value is an array (ex: `['lab_one', 'lab_three']`)
not 1 element.

Comment: @Vega Changes made. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: What if I wanted to change tr style when checkbox is clicked ??

Comment: @besmir You could use [`$.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `TR`, and then call [`$.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add a class to it. See http://jsbin.com/axivof/edit

Comment: One more thing Jonathan, let's say o1 contains values #lab_one and #lab_three, and o2 contains values #lab_two and #lab_three, it seems that checkbox #lab_three when o1 is selected won't check up!

Comment: @besmir This is because the example in your question suggested each option set would have unique children, and not share elements. If you want to share elements, the code needs to be modified slightly: http://jsbin.com/onapem/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `var`'s as an object and the simply iterate over the selections and check the checkboxes. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/VDe7G/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selections = {
                  o1: ['lab_one', 'lab_three'],
                  o2: ['lab_two', 'lab_six'],
                  o3: ['lab_four', 'lab_five']
    };

    var $checkbox = $(':checkbox');

    $("#lab_abbr").on("change", function(e)  {

        $.each ($checkbox, function (i, ck) { //uncheck all checkbox
            this.checked = false;
        });

        $.each($(this).val(), function (idx, val) { //iterate over selected options
            $.each (selections[val], function (i, v) { //iterate over the selections
                $('#' + v).prop('checked', true); //set the checkbox
            });        
        });        
    });
});
```