# mapped values in jquery have to be unique

Tags: jquery, mapping, html-select

This is a question concerning the post on this site at...
[jquery checkbox check using arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523981/jquery-checkbox-check-using-arrays)

There was a demo link to http://jsbin.com/onapem/2/edit and the code was...

```
<select id="lab_abbr" multiple >
  <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="lab[one]" id="lab_one" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[two]" id="lab_two" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[three]" id="lab_three" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[four]" id="lab_four" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[five]" id="lab_five" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[six]" id="lab_six" />
```

JS

```
var mapping = { 'o1' : ['lab_one', 'lab_three'], 'o2' : ['lab_two', 'lab_six'], 
                'o3' : ['lab_four', 'lab_five'] };

$("#lab_abbr").on("change", function () {
  $.each( this.options, function () {
    $( "#" + mapping[ this.value ].join(", #") ).prop("checked", this.selected); 
  });
});
```

I would like to use this functionality but you can only map a value once. So if I wanted 'lab_one' to be mapped to o3 as well as o1 it can't be done. It just uses the last case so having the effect of taking 'lab_one' away from o1. It would be nice to do this. For example I would like, when clicking on a footballer to have the teams he has scored against checked. Is there a way to assign value multiple times?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless you have huge mappings simply put 'lab_one' in the o3 array

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the checkboxes you'd like to check in a data attribute attached to each option, and then check or uncheck boxes based on that.

HTML:

```
<select id="lab_abbr" multiple >
  <option value="o1" data-elem="one, three"      >Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2" data-elem="two, six"        >Option 2</option>
  <option value="o3" data-elem="one, four, five" >Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="lab[one]"   id="lab_one"   />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[two]"   id="lab_two"   />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[three]" id="lab_three" />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[four]"  id="lab_four"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[five]"  id="lab_five"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="lab[six]"   id="lab_six"   />
```

JS

```
$("#lab_abbr").on("change", function () {
    var elems = $.map($('option:selected', this).data('elem').split(','), function(x) {
         return $.trim(x);
    });
    $('[name^="lab\\["]').prop('checked', function() {
        return $.inArray(this.id.replace('lab_',''), elems) != -1;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GSfcw/1/)

Comment: Really thanks for your replies, sorry for not getting back sooner but I didn't receive an email notification of responses. @patrickevans as I understand your comment I think this was the problem I was having, adding lab_one to o3 took it away from o1. I maybe misunderstood what you say but thank you for responding.

Comment: Thank You @adeneo that does the trick. I'm quite new to jquery so some of your syntax is a bit complex but I'm going to break it down and see exactly how it works but it does work brilliantly. Thank You for helping me.